# can I use Moq to grab values that are passed into a public method of an object that is not a mock?

Tags: moq, integration-testing

I'm writing a unit test for FluentMigrator. I am testing a method that gets called `n` times in succession. What I'd like to do is grab the successive inputs and stow them in a SortedList, so that I can verify the methods were called in the right order, then pass those inputs to the actual method -- like a temporary redirect. But, after reading the docs etc, I can't get it to work.

Code in the test:

```
        var listOfVersions = new SortedList<int, long>();
        int i = 0;

        var runnerMock = Mock.Get(_runner); // runner is a MigrationRunner
        runnerMock.Setup(r => r.RollbackToVersion(2))
            .Callback((long v) =>
            {
                listOfVersions.Add(i, v);
                i++;
                _runner.RollbackToVersion(v, true);                 });

        _runner.RollbackToVersion(2);
```

The error:

```
System.ArgumentException : Object instance was not created by Moq.
Parameter name: mocked
```

I'm coming from Moles, where dipping into the behavior of an object and then redirecting it isn't unusual. Maybe it is in Moq?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Really mocking frameworks fall into 2 camps. The ones that can mock anything and the other than can only mock Interfaces, Abstract/Virtual methods.

This is because they use very much a different interception technology. Moq, RhinoMocks etc use Castle's Dynamic Proxy Generator under the hood which all it does create an instance that exposes the same public interface. It uses this to record interactions with that object so you can verify on it. Abstract and Virtual members can be mocked cause it can derive from that class and prevent calls to the base class.

However Moles and TypeMock Isloator play around with the IL directly. I know for TypeMock it actually weaves IL into the methods you are trying to mock so you can intercept and record interactions on it for testing (It also stops further processing of the methods also). I know that Moles creates another assembly and you refer to that in your test method but I imagine it does very similar things to TypeMock.

If you want to mock concrete non overrideable methods you will have to use that latter frameworks.

Comment: Thanks, that lines up with what I was thinking.